# What is the midsection of a frustum and how do you calculate its perimeter?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

A doubt while reading ["How to solve it" by George Polya](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/069111966X).

Given the figure below:

[image]

**What is the midsection of this figure and how would you calculate its perimeter?** (Would be great if you could tell me how to find it on the diagram).

Quoting from the book the midsection is defined as :

> We call here mid-section the intersection of the frustum with a plane
>   which is parallel both to the lower base and to the upper base of the
>   frustum and bisects the altitude.

So is it the dotted area or the area with the solid line in the figure? You see this does not make since to me because he says the midsection bisects the altitude. There is no such construct on the given figure, so it must be something else. *Also how can a plane bisect the altitude, a planar figure is 2D right? And the height is a 3D aspect right?*

How would you also calculate the perimeter of that midsection ?

If can please do briefly describe what a midsection is? Is it something that only exists in solid objects or is present in objects of planar geometry as well?

Comment: The figure does not show the midsection. The midsection is a circle halfway between (and in a plane parallel to) the top and bottom of the frustrum.

Comment: @Blue I am not understanding at all. So the midsection is 2D? Then how can it bisect the altitude? Is it something like this. (https://imgur.com/a/kxeUfmG)

Comment: @Blue Can you please add a diagram ?

Comment: Do you understand that a frustrum is created by cutting-off the tip of a $3D$ cone? A midsection is made by the same kind of cut.

Comment: @Blue Yes I understand now. But here is a funny doubt, what is the midsection? If I cut the figure exactly in half I get 2 figures. So is the midsection the one on the top or the one on the bottom?

Comment: Cut the figure exactly in half, but don't separate the pieces. The midsection is simply the circle where the top piece meets the bottom piece.

Comment: @ng newbie Mid section does not mean any symmetry of cut parts. It simply or nominally means situation at middle of the remaining frustum height.

Comment: @Narasimham: That should be an answer, not an edit to the question. I have moved your edited figure to your answer instead, such that it is clear _what the OP actually asked_.

Comment: Thanks for shifting it. Regards

Comment: I think some of the confusion here is caused by the word "section". In everyday language that sounds like it suggests a _piece_ of the entire frustrum, while in this particular context it's just a 2D surface that is the inter_section_ of the body and a plane -- in other words a particular chosen _cross section_.

Answer (score 1):

The midsection as defined in the question is the disk colored in yellow here:

[image: edited figure from the question]

It is necessary to appreciate that there is a proportionality between radius and height from apex by means of similar triangles. The straight generator of cone passes through origin at apex of originating cone. You can find radius and height even perimeter at half, quarter, three quarter frustum height also.

Also let $x$ be distance from cone apex to center of top circle of frustum as shown:

$$ \tan \alpha=\frac{\dfrac{R+r}{2}}{(x+h/2)} $$

Perimeter is simply the average at mid-section

$$ p_{mid-section}= \pi (R+r)$$

[image]

Comment: I am afraid I don't have much experience with calculus, and I can't understand what you mean by "generator"

Comment: By rotating slant line $OA$ about axis $OCX$ you get the swept surface of cone. So we can call $OA$ as the generator or meridian of the cone.If you cut the cone by a plane 1) at top you get  top section diameter $EF$ 2) at bottom you get  bottom  diameter $AB $. At mid-section the shown red line.

Answer (score 0):

Just $$2\pi\cdot\frac{R+r}{2}=\pi(R+r).$$

Because a perimeter of the circle with radius $x$ it's $2\pi x$.

The needed midsection it's a circle with diameter, which is a midline of the trapezoid with bases $2R$ and $2r$ and this midline is equal to $\frac{2R+2r}{2}=R+r.$

Id est, the radius of the circle is equal to $\frac{R+r}{2}.$

Comment: Yes but what is the midsection for this figure? Anyway you can tell me how to find it on the diagram?

Comment: Could you please elaborate as to how you are calculating the perimeter of the midsection ?

Comment: @ng.newbie I fixed and added something. See now.